# How can i detected and controll object opencv?

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, computer-vision, object-tracking

I am using an android camera that should control a robot. By selecting an object on a screen, the robot should follow this object. I detected contours on the images and also a bounding rectangle, however I don't know how to proceed any further.

```
    Mat src = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, src);
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 100, 200);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    // find contours:
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(src, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(1, 1, 255), 1);
        org.opencv.core.Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(contourIdx));
        Imgproc.rectangle(src, rect.tl(), rect.br(), Scalar.all(Color.BLUE), 2);
        
    }
    Core.extractChannel(gray, src, 0);
    Bitmap tempBmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
    Utils.matToBitmap(src, tempBmp1);
    im_screen.setImageBitmap(tempBmp1);
```

How can I do this in Java to get an image like this? display each object separately?

[image: img]

Comment: So if you already detected the object and so on, what makes this an opencv question? seems like your question is more about the control of the robot and not about image processing?

Comment: I need to capture an object without using standard library objects.
For example, I select a dog bowl on my phone, the program must understand that it requires a call.

Comment: So some stuff... first your example image does not make sense. What is this? why is it all of a sudden black and white? Are you overlaying the canny edge detection on the original image? and second, what would you need to control the robot? It will be basically `if clicked then do`?

Comment: I take out a fragment from the overall picture and highlight the contours. What unique parameters can be taken to detect an object in the overall picture?

Comment: Can you please include an image of the input image you have and not the processed one, it's hard to tell which features you should choose.

Comment: Am not so sure you understood what I said with input image, the image that you included in the post is already processed with a bounding box and a different color for each object, hence, you are already detecting the objects. Which brings me back to my question, what is your question about? detecting objects or controlling the robot???

Comment: I said about robot for more understanding my question))). So first i need to get object from image as on the photo. I have find this on the Python but dont understand how can i resolve its on the java.

Comment: What robot are you using? are there any microprocessors involved? ports? your question needs a lot more detail. There is nothing in your code that defines any sort of communication to an external object, it is mainly opencv stuff, which made me think that your question is about image processing. Please adjust your post into a focused question. Or better yet, go to another stack where they deal with robotics or micro-processors